# Laravel: a model that belongs to two other models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In laravel, is there a way to get the list of objects that belong to two models?

For example,

Model transactions:
belongs to users
belongs to category

Model user:
has many transactions

Model category:
has many transactions

Assuming these relationships are correctly defined, what kind of query would you make in, say the controller, to access the set of transactions that belongs to user x and category y?

Comment: Show us what you did so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `Transaction` table has the foreign keys for `user_id` and `category_id`, you could do:

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('user_id', '=', 'x')
                          ->where('category_id ', '=', 'y')
                          ->get();
```